# MySQL - trigger ON UPDATE without changing any other columns

Tags: mysql

Example table is defined like this:

```sql
create table testtable (
    some_id int primary key,
    ts timestamp default 0 on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    <zero or more columns...>
);
```

Is it possible to run UPDATE query on this table, given `some_id`, so that `ts` gets updated to the current timestamp for that row?
One way would be using

```sql
UPDATE testtable SET column1 = column1 WHERE some_id = %s
```

however, are there any drawbacks to this? What about when the table only has two columns - `some_id` and `ts` in this case?

Comment: That seems like how it works.  The only downside is in 2038 Timestamp stops working, but thats plenty of time for the DB's to update and allow 64 bit solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE testtable SET ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE some_id = %s;
```